# 0603 LED resistor values

Tags: led, resistors, atmega328p

I have two LEDs

The first one is directly attached to 3V3 and the other one is attacked to the SCK line on AT Mega 328P

Here's the datasheet for the led (I am using the same LED)
http://www.image.micros.com.pl/_dane_techniczne_auto/olbs.03w0800.pdf

And the schematic bits:
[image]
[image]

Is my 1K resistor too much for these LEDs? I want to be able to see them at at least 50% brightness

Comment: The LED will also add about 100 pF of capacitance. What is the clock frequency? 50%brightness is about 10 mA. With forward vorlage drop in the range 2.9 to 3.2, operating at 3.3 V wil create a huge variation in brightness of the LED thereby even dropping the SCK line

Comment: The capacitance will not be a problem since it is in series with the 1k resistor. Not sure how much current you will get though, so the LED may not be very bright. Is the SCK net being used as a clock? If not, I would suggest a much smaller resistor. Well, the capacitance could be a problem if you try to run SCK very fast, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the LED characteristics.  What is the forward voltage drop across the LEDs? What current are you targeting?  This is a relatively easy thing to calculate.  The difference between the system voltage, in your case 3.3V, and the forward voltage drop is what is left across your resistor.  Use Ohms' law to find the current.

Comment: The forward voltage is min 3 and 3.2 typically, as described by the datasheet. IF=20mA

Comment: Do I actually need a resistor at all for this one?

Comment: You absolutely need the resistor as it is the component that explicitly limits the current to a controlled level. Using the typical forward voltage of 3v, that leaves 0.3v across the resistor. Use V = I*R to find the resistance for a desired current.

Comment: 0.3V = 300mV and the current desired is 20mA, this leads me to 15 Ohm resistor?

Comment: Also, is using less resistors useful for battery efficiency? I know in this case we are using resistors not to blow up an LED, but in general, ideally, you would not use one, right? Sorry if this question seems a bit foolish

Comment: 15 ohm would the correct value for your conditions.  You would always need the resistor as part of that circuit to control the current.  Without it, the only thing limiting the current is the internal resistance of the diode, drive strength of the IO pin that's driving it, power supply, etc.  You don't want to push any of those to their limits. For battery efficiency, in general, the more current you draw from a battery the less time it will last.  Think of a bucket of water, which represents the battery and its charge. The more water that flows out of the bucket, the quicker it will be empty.